# Android : How to dynamically add selected Document to imageview as a Preview/Thumbnail Inside a Gridview

Tags: android, gridview, android-arrayadapter, baseadapter

I have an android application where I need to implement a Gridview which contains an imageview and a TextView, also have a button to add new view to the gridview.When i click on this button a file chooser will come and can select any document like pdf,docs,images,etc from my device.Then i want to display this document as an image in the gridview with its name.How can i do that?This is exactly the same like if we got a mail with attachments(images,pdf,docs,..), then we can see it as images when we open that mail.That is we can see a preview image of that document before we click on each document as below.I need exactly the same feature in my gridview.
[image: Attachment] 
Below is the code that i had used to display the file chooser.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
    intent.setType("*/*"); 
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    try {
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"),FILE_SELECT_CODE);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("browseClick :"+ex);
    }
```

And i have implemented the

```
onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){}
```

to do the work after selecting the file.After so much of research i got a method to create the thumbnail of a video file as below.

```
ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filePath, kind);
```

But didn't find anything to get the thumbnail of other documents.

I don't know how to show documents in gridview like images.Please help me.

Comment: for docs normally mail clients show icons for pdf , word file etc and thumbnail for images.
When you select file check the mimeType if it is image show thumbnail on imageview
If it is pdf then show pdf icon (put icon in drawable folder) and show that one same case with other files.

Comment: but in mail i think we can see the content of pdf as like a samll image before we open the pdf.

Comment: no we can put name of pdf in textView

Comment: @KhizarHayat is there any way to do this??

Comment: do not know exactly but this link is describing same as i said
have a [look](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447848/how-to-show-preview-of-file-and-open-up-file-in-its-application-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

To create such a thumbnail, of course you need to create a thumbnail of the pdf first. What you are seeing in the web which provides out of the box solutions to show the pdf content as the thumbnail but for android things are not that smooth. What i can suggest you is to create the convert any of the page in the image format and than show that converted image as the thumbnail for your pdf. There is no straight way in android to do it so you have to be depended on third party libraries like [this](https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android), it the ported version of pdfbox available for java or you can give [this](https://www.idrsolutions.com/jpedal/convert-pdf-to-images) library a try. There is [this](https://java.net/projects/pdf-renderer/downloads) another library which is just available for java not sure if it would work for android too(I have not tried it yet).
If its not utmost necessity, i would suggest you to just show the pdf indicator drawable because just to show the pdf, increasing apk size is not a wise decision by including thsese libraries. Also there are some complex and high graphics containing pdf which could just crash your apps by increasing java heap size.

Answer (score 0):

There is PdfRenderer library for ".pdf" files.

Android document is here, [PDF Renderer Library](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer.html). Unfortunately, this library added API 21.

There is nice example for this library [Create and Display PDF within Android Application](http://androidsrc.net/create-and-display-pdf-within-android-application/)

> This code in this website. You can create thumbnail with this code.

```
    @TargetApi( Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP )
    private void generateImageFromPdf(String filePath) {

// filePath must be like : Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath()+"/42080.pdf"

        File file = new File(filePath);
// FileDescriptor for file, it allows you to close file when you are
// done with it
        ParcelFileDescriptor mFileDescriptor = null;
        try {
            mFileDescriptor = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file,
                    ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
// PdfRenderer enables rendering a PDF document
        PdfRenderer mPdfRenderer = null;
        try {
            mPdfRenderer = new PdfRenderer(mFileDescriptor);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

// Open page with specified index
        PdfRenderer.Page mCurrentPage = mPdfRenderer.openPage(0);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mCurrentPage.getWidth(),
                mCurrentPage.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

// Pdf page is rendered on Bitmap
        mCurrentPage.render(bitmap, null, null,
                PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);
// Set rendered bitmap to ImageView (pdfView in my case)
        ImageView pdfView = (ImageView) findViewById( R.id.bitmap );
        pdfView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


        mCurrentPage.close();
        mPdfRenderer.close();
        try {
            mFileDescriptor.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```